# how to convert sql command to yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
select g_code
from t_graph_name
where character_length(g_code) = 5
```

Comment: By Reading the Docs

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about [build Query](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) in Yii2..also you can read about [active record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record) too.

after reading it, you can see you can build it by Query builder like this:

```
$rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['g_code'])
    ->from('t_graph_name')
    ->where('character_length(g_code) = 5')
    ->all();
```